# PyQt5 Dialog window opens without layout

Tags: layout, dialog, pyqt5, python-3.6

When I load a dialog (QMainWindow) window from within my mainwindow (QMainWindow), it loads without layout, even though the setupUi() function is called.

The important pieces of code are here below, [click here](https://pastebin.com/m7HGED97) for pastebin link to full code

```
class Ui_Dialog(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        ...

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        ....
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        ...
        self.auto_sap_btn = QPushButton(Form)
        self.auto_sap_btn.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 61, 25))
        self.auto_sap_btn.setObjectName('auto_sap_btn')
        self.auto_sap_btn.clicked.connect(self.openDialog)

    def openDialog(self):
        self.window = Ui_Dialog(self)
        self.window.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.move(600, 500)
        self.window.show()
```

Right now my dialog looks like this:

Failed dialog layout

[image]

When I load the dialog on its own from its own script created by:

```
pyuic5 -x dialog.ui -o dialog.py
```

it looks like this:

Proper dialog layout

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a design based on a Template in Qt Designer, then when you have to pass the appropriate widget, when you created Ui_Dialog you surely used `Dialog with Buttons Right` so in this case you should use a QDialog instead of QMainWindow:

```
class Ui_Dialog(QDialog): # change QMainWindow to QDialog
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        [...]
```

Another mistake is to use the `setupUi()` method a second time since this method is responsible for filling in the widget, by calling it 2 times you will be adding more widgets unnecessarily:

```
def openDialog(self):
    self.window = Ui_Dialog(self)
    self.window.move(600, 500)
    self.window.show()
```

Comment: You're completely right. I totally missed the 2nd time setupUi was ran. I followed this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dRRpbDFnMHI), and he used QMainWindow, but after changing it to QDialog it works like a charm. Thanks for the help!